# Is storing data in localStorage or sesssionStorage the only way to persist data in react?

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm building an e-commerce website using react and symfony.

I'm tryin to save a user's info, and I'm using context api to do that, but the issue is that data isn't persisting when page is refreshed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: As another option, URL's query parameters also can be used to achieve data persistence, but it's not suitable for all cases, most of the time either `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` is the right solution to go

Comment: You can also use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API if the amount of data is significant.

Comment: @ArturMinin URL's query params is def not the appropriate way to achieve this, at least for my case where I want to persist sensitive data. Is storing data in localStorage or sessionStorage secure?

Answer (score 1):

It's highly discouraged to store any senstive information in the browser storage because it opens the door for vulnerabilities.

The user information -and other data- are provided by the backend. One way you can do it is to create an [HTTP-Only cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) that holds the user token and create an endpoint that provides the needed user information. Once the application starts, that request is sent once. If the cookie is valid, the endpoint will return the user information then you can use these information in your application without storing anything in the browser storage.

Every time the page is refreshed, you send that request and it will get the user information.

The topic you are asking about tackles different parts and its implementation differs according to the backend stack that you are using. I would suggest you check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uboIb2__qqs) or other resource to understand how to implement it.

Comment: this, basically u save data in local storage which can be read from everyone on the site.  Do you want save carts for example so this is no problem.

Comment: @StefanBD It's true that I want to do that, but the question I asked was about figuring out whether or not the user is logged in and based on that the right component should be rendered. So, I'm trying to come up with a solution that is secure to avoid xss attacks for example.

Comment: if you want check if the user have the rigth to see the form you can save "is_logged_in = 1" in the local storage this is not the problem but you should secure it on the server side and check the perms twice. If a hacker set the storage hey maybe get the form but he can do nothing with

Comment: other way would usestates, perform a api call with cookie or authcode  and on respose you tell the react app thaht the user is logged in, please render it